# Swift / iOS7: UIPickerView is Gray if Initially Hidden

Tags: xcode, swift, ios7, uipickerview

I have added a UIPickerView in Interface Builder. Its "Show Selection Indicator" is checked.

Inside View Did Load of the View, I have:

```
businessCategoryPicker?.dataSource = self
businessCategoryPicker.delegate = self
businessCategoryText.inputView = businessCategoryPicker
businessCategoryPicker.hidden = true
```

Now when I tap the text field, it brings up the picker but it is all Grayed out.

If I remove the last line from above code. The contents of picker come back and work fine but now I have  the picker showing up as soon as the view appears which is not how I want it.

Am I missing something?

Comment: No need to write last line because if you are writing then your picker view get hidden.

Comment: @Ashok: read the question again

Comment: i have read the question. i think your doing something wrong. you have used ActionSheet or not. if yes, then your output is right.